# BigInt modulo float

Tags: javascript, modulo, bigint

I would like to calculate the a `bigint` modulo a `number` (float)

As `a % b` will necessarily be lower than `b`, the result can be expressed as a `number`.

example: with 10 000 000 000 000 000 004 modulo 1.43
expected result: 1.13

```js
10_000_000_000_000_000_004 % 1.43
//  0.042653000061321444

10_000_000_000_000_000_004n % 1.43
//  TypeError: can't convert BigInt to number
```

how can i create a bigModulo function with this signature?

```js
function bigModulo(numerator: bigint, denominator: number): number
```

Answer (score 2):

The calculation can be solved by converting it into a `bigint`-only problem, apply `bigint`-modulo and then convert it back to the original scale:

```js
function bigModulo(numerator: bigint, denominator: number): number {
  if (!denominator) return NaN;
  let scale = 1;
  while (denominator % 1 !== 0) {
    numerator *= 10n;
    denominator *= 10;
    scale *= 10;
  }
  return Number(numerator % BigInt(denominator)) / scale;
}

bigModulo(10_000_000_000_000_000_004n, 1.43); //1.13
```

Comment: One small issue with your edit is that it will break down as denominator approaches `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (ex: `900_719_925_474_099.5`), since multiplying it by 10 becomes lossy. But it's an extreme case. :-) (Despite that, this seems a better approach than the earlier one involving conversion to string, but I can't upvote again, so...)

Comment: The earlier version also hits this limit with such extreme values.

Comment: 'Tis true... :-)

Comment: Note that this approach has other numerical issues, e.g. `bigModulo(1000000000000000n, 1/7)` should return `0` but returns `0.1142857142857144`; `bigModulo(1234567n, 1234567.0000000001)` should return `1234567` but returns `0`. I think to solve this accurately you'd need to use "BigDecimal" or "Rational" data types (provided by some library, as JS doesn't have either of those).

Comment: @jmrk `1234567.0000000001 === 1234567 // true`

Comment: @Yukulélé oops, fair point. And I can't seem to construct a case that exhibits the accidental rounding-down I was expecting to see... so I guess that particular failure mode can't happen after all.